# Subscript out of Range when choosing a Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

When I tried to get excel to  choose which workbook to use, it gives me an error for subscript out of range. I don't know whether I have to reference which folder it originates from. They are all in the same folder. I looked through other peoples solutions,but I don't have neither the same format nor task. The error is  on the line where it assigns workbook numbers

```
Sub bringbookstogether()

Dim currentsheet As Worksheet
Set currentsheet = Application.ActiveSheet

Dim othersheets As Worksheet

Dim wbook As Workbook

Dim c As String

'assigns the number to start with

Dim a, b, d As Integer

a = 4
b = 6
d = 1

'assigns workbook numbers
If (d = 1) Then
    Set wbook = Workbooks("MaintPrep Sheet 1st")
    Else
    If (d = 2) Then
        Set wbook = Workbooks("MaintPrep Sheet 2nd")
        Else
        If (d = 3) Then
            Set wbook = Workbooks("MaintPrep Sheet 3rd")
        End If
    End If
End If

'End if it's done with all the workbooks

Do Until (d = 4)

'Looks for the sheet that has the same name

Do While (c = currentsheet.Name)

'Ends in row 99

Do While (b < 99)

'Ends in Column 52

Do While (a < 52)

currentsheet.Cells(b, a) = currentsheet.Cells(b, a) + Workbooks(d).Sheets(c).Cells(b, a)

a = a + 1
Loop

b = b + 1
Loop

Loop

d = d + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's better to use the full filename: 
`Workbooks("MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsx")` etc.

Second of all, this code will error as soon as one of the Workbooks you're trying to access is not currently opened. If a Workbook is not open, it doesn't exist within the current context and thus Excel will throw error 91.

To fix this, you could do:

```
Sub a()
Dim wb As Workbook

On Error Resume Next 'To avoid error 91
Set wb = Workbooks("MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0 'To avoid not seeing other errors.

If Not wb Is Nothing Then
    'Do stuff
    MsgBox "Opened!"
Else
    'Handle the fact that it's missing
    MsgBox "Not open!"
End If

'Alternatively, OPEN the workbook if you couldn't set it in the first place:
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks("MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0

If wb Is Nothing Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\FullPath\MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsx")
    'Do stuff
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do I have to do one for each Workbook?

Comment: Depends on your use case. You could also just assume the Workbooks are closed by default and use `Workbooks.Open("path\filename.xlsx")` when setting the `wbook` variable.